# Where should I put test utility functions in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust

I have the following code defining a path where generated files can be placed:

```
fn gen_test_dir() -> tempdir::TempDir {                                        
    tempdir::TempDir::new_in(Path::new("/tmp"), "filesyncer-tests").unwrap()   
}
```

This function is defined in `tests/lib.rs`, used in the tests in that file and I would also like to use it in the unit tests located in `src/lib.rs`.

Is this possible to achieve without compiling the utility functions into the non-test binary and without duplicating code?

Comment: Can't you move that funcionality into `src/lib.rs` and then use it in `tests/lib.rs`?

Comment: @DanielFath I tried this and annotated with `#[test]` to avoid compiling into release-binary and received this error: "functions used as tests must have signature fn()
 -> ()"

Comment: Can you try putting `#cfg(not(test))` that will remove your code, during non-test phases.

Comment: I think you mean `#[cfg(test)]`.  I tend to have a `#[cfg(test)] mod tests` in my lib.rs (or submodules), into which I put all the unit test functions and any utilities they need.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson Ahh this seems to work. If you put it in an answer, I can mark it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I do is put my unit tests with any other utilities into a submodule protected with `#[cfg(test)]`:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {  // The contents could be a separate file if it helps organisation
    // Not a test, but available to tests.
    fn some_utility(s: String) -> u32 {
        ...
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_foo() {
        assert_eq!(...);
    }
    // more tests
}
```

Comment: What about integration tests? I need to integrate with a database, but I don't want to have to create a dependency just for tests. Integration tests work well for my problem up until I need to reuse utility functions. I guess I'll go and create a testutil crate...

Answer (score 23):

You can import from your `#[cfg(test)]` modules from other `#[cfg(test)]` modules, so, for example, in `main.rs` or in some other module, you can do something like:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod test_util {
    pub fn return_two() -> usize { 2 }
}
```

and then from anywhere else in your project:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use crate::test_util::return_two;

    #[test]
    fn test_return_two() {
        assert_eq!(return_two(), 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Test mode](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/testing.html#the-test-attribute) (the rustc --test flag) also seems to be enabled for benches. It doesn't seem to be enabled for [honggfuzz-rs](https://github.com/rust-fuzz/honggfuzz-rs) targets however.

Comment: for some reason this just doesnt work for me