# How to share common code between Cargo project examples?

Tags: rust, project, rust-cargo

What is the common way to share code between multiple [examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html?highlight=examples#examples) defined as part of a Cargo project?

This is my library project:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── src/
│   └── lib.rs
├── examples/
│   └── example-A/
│   │    └── main.rs
│   └── example-B/
│       └── main.rs
```

I need to share some code only between `example-A` and `example-B`. Where should the shared code live, and how can I refer to it from these two examples?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539729/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-to-have-shared-utility-functions-for-integration-tests