# What is an idiomatic way to implement a trait only for tests across multiple crates?

Tags: testing, rust

I work in a workspace with dozens of crates. One of those crates exposes a trait. As a mock, I implement that trait for `()` with `unimplemented!` in every function (they're not actually used). I'd like that implementation to be available from the other crates, but only during the tests: what is the idiomatic way (the handiest) to do so?

For now, the implementation is behind a `mock` feature, and I add this crate with the `mock` feature as a dev dependency in a random crate. That forces the compiler to take that implementation into account during the tests. It's an ugly hack, so I'd rather have another way.

Comment: Why not implement the trait in the test crate for a type `struct Dummy;` defined in that same test crate rather than for `()`?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [What is an idiomatic way to have shared utility functions for integration tests and benchmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44539729/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster I would create a crate for utilities, like some functions, but it would be kinda weird for trait implementations

Comment: @Boiethios there are three separate answers on that post.

Answer (score 0):

Items gated with `test` are not exported from a crate, even for crates that use it as a dev dependency.

[As of Rust 1.51.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2957-cargo-features2.md), you can work around that by using a custom feature.

In `Cargo.toml`:

```
[features]
test-traits = []
```

In the code:

```
#[cfg(feature = "test-traits")]
impl MyTrait for MyStruct {}
```

In crates that depend on it, you can enable the new resolover:

```
[package]
resolver = "2"
```

And add a dev dependency that enables the feature:

```
[dev-dependencies]
your_crate = { version = "1.0", features = ["test-traits"] }
```

Without the new resolver enabled all features are additive across targets, so enabling the feature in `dev-dependencies` would enable it for non-test code too. With the new resolver this is now handled more like you would expect.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've modified my question so it's clearer

Comment: @Boiethios I updated the answer, but I hadn't seen your question update. I think this is currently the best option.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yup. I'll update to add that.