# How to compile to both wasm and binary in a Rust crate?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I'm writing the back-end for a web application and would like to reuse some logic for client-side. I want to use wasm to generate a library which Javascript can use. Suppose the logic is in lib.rs. What should I do, so that:

1. The back-end can import and use the code in lib.rs as normal, also cargo build generates a binary as expected.
2. Rust generates a wasm library for lib.rs

I tried adding these to my cargo file (by following this: [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946646/rust-package-with-both-a-library-and-a-binary)):

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[[bin]]
name = "mybin"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

But it seems like cargo is building my binary for the browser, so it is missing all the sys crate.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask for only your library to be built using the `--lib` option.

```sh
cargo build --lib --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to specify different compile target for bin and lib in the toml file, so that `cargo build` will build both?

Comment: @Gnut Not that I know of — a single `cargo build` command only ever builds for one target.

Answer (score 1):

So my current approach is to create a separate package for lib.rs and use it as a dependency for the back-end, as outlined in here:
[What is an idiomatic way to have shared utility functions for integration tests and benchmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539729/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-to-have-shared-utility-functions-for-integration-tests/44545091#44545091)
It seems to work well enough.