# Cannot import a module in an integration test

Tags: rust

I am trying to configure an example project in Rust to work.

My structure is:

- `src/potter.rs`
- `tests/tests.rs`

And my `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "potter"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["my name"]
[dependencies]
```

My `potter.rs` contains:

```
pub mod potter {
    pub struct Potter {

    }

    impl Potter  {
        pub fn new() -> Potter {
         return Potter {};
        }
    }

}
```

And my `tests.rs` contains:

```
use potter::Potter;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {

        let pot = potter::Potter::new();
        assert_eq!(2 + 2, 4);
    }
```

But I receive this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `potter`
 --> tests/tests.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use potter::Potter;
  |     ^^^^^^ Maybe a missing `extern crate potter;`?

error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `potter`
 --> tests/tests.rs:6:19
  |
6 |         let pot = potter::Potter::new();
  |                   ^^^^^^ Use of undeclared type or module `potter`

warning: unused import: `potter::Potter`
 --> tests/tests.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use potter::Potter;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default
```

If I add `extern crate potter;`, it doesn't fix anything...

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `potter`
 --> tests/tests.rs:1:1
  |
1 | extern crate potter;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

Comment: I removed the  `pub mod potter` and the error continues.

Comment: I applied the solution from the duplicated answer, it seems not work.

Comment: I  renamed my potter.rs to lib.rs but it keeps not working...

Comment: I had the same error because I was trying to reference modules declared in `main.rs` which I had assumed would work. As soon as I moved the logic into `lib.rs` and referenced that from both `main.rs` and the tests then everything worked.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go back and [reread *The Rust Programming Language* about packages, crates, modules and the filesystem](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html).

Common pain points:

- Every programming language has its own way of dealing with files — you cannot just assume that because you've used any other language that you will magically get Rust's take on it. That's why you should [go back and re-read the book chapter on it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html).
- Each file defines a module. Your `lib.rs` defines a module of the same name as your crate; a `mod.rs` defines a module of the same name as the directory it's in; every other file defines a module of the name of the file.
- The root of your library crate **must** be `lib.rs`; binary crates may use `main.rs`.
- No, you really shouldn't try to do non-idiomatic filesystem organization. There are tricks to do most anything you want; these are terrible ideas unless you are already an advanced Rust user.
- Idiomatic Rust does not generally place "one type per file" like many other languages. Yes, really. You can have multiple things in one file.
- Unit tests usually live in the same file as the code it's testing. Sometimes they will be split out into a file containing the submodule, but that's uncommon.
- Integration tests, examples, benchmarks all have to import the crate like any other user of the crate and can only use the public API.

---

To fix your issue:

1. Move your `src/potter.rs` to `src/lib.rs`.
2. Remove `pub mod potter` from `src/lib.rs`. Not *strictly* required, but removes needless nesting of modules.
3. Add `extern crate potter` to your integration test `tests/tests.rs` (Only needed if you are using Rust 2015).

**filesystem**

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   └── lib.rs
├── target
└── tests
    └── tests.rs
```

**src/lib.rs**

```
pub struct Potter {}

impl Potter {
    pub fn new() -> Potter {
       Potter {}
    }
}
```

**tests/tests.rs**

```
use potter::Potter;

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    let pot = Potter::new();
    assert_eq!(2 + 2, 4);
}
```

Comment: I've `tests/common.rs` where I'm doing this: `#[macro_use] extern crate mylib;` but it says *"an `extern crate` **loading macros** must be at the crate root"*. So I'm wondering which file is *"crate root"* for *tests* directory? Is there any analogous to *src/lib.rs*?

Comment: @Nawaz every single file in the `tests` directory is compiled as a separate binary crate. Each of those is the crate root. See also [Where should I put test utility functions in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37993886/155423); [What is an idiomatic way to have shared utility functions for integration tests and benchmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44539729/155423).

Comment: So why does `#[macro_use] extern ... `  not work for `tests/common.rs` and it is asking me to put in some  `crate root`. What `crate root` is, is not clearly defined it seems.

Comment: Because you haven't put it at the crate root. "crate root" is a well-defined term - it's the entrypoint of the crate. **Every single file in the tests directory** is compiled as a separate binary crate. That means that your `tests/common.rs` is being compiled as a binary so that's one crate root (probably not what you want, either). Presumably you are also importing that file as a module from another file like `tests/foo.rs` — foo.rs is **also** a crate root.

Comment: Ohh.. I see. I'm getting that error because of `mod common;` as it is being used as sorta library/utility, not executable!

Comment: I moved all the content from `tests/common.rs` to `tests/common/mod.rs` and now I'm able to do `mod common;` in other test files. It works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also need to make sure that you have the correct linkage. That is, `[lib]` in your `Cargo.toml` with the right settings https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html. I had `crate-type=cdylib`, and it wouldn't work. https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6659

Comment: "Unit tests usually live in the same file as the code it's testing." That's absolutely wild. Do people really find that maintainable?

Comment: @MatthewDean yes.

Comment: What about using `super::*`, does it help in this case? I am new to rustc

Comment: Considering that answer, if you want to 100% test coverage, all your code should aside inside lib.rs, that's totally unacceptable!

Comment: @MatthewDean I don't love the practice of inlined unit tests--it tends to make for rather lengthy files.  But I find extracting the unit tests to separate file(s) in a subfolder to be very maintainable.  The unit tests are treated as a submodule by the compiler either way, but in a subfolder helps with both cohesion and separation of concerns.

Comment: @U007D, could you provide an example?  When I try to create a subdirectory for tests, I run into scoping problems.  Do you put the test code in a tests/mod.rs file?  What mod keywords do you have to use?  if you have a github repo that illustrates this, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Gardener, sure. For completeness, a `tests` folder *in the crate root* is actually for integration tests and does not see everything that a unit test can (with that said, unit tests which frequently rely on private implementation details are probably a code smell). If you create folders (I create `unit_tests` folders for clarity) *under* `src`, you should have no scoping issues. Here's an example: https://github.com/U007D/islands. Take a look specifically at [`src/world.rs`](https://github.com/U007D/islands/blob/main/src/world.rs) to see a working example with modularized unit tests.