# How do I import submodules in another submodule which are part of the tests/ directory?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My goal is to write a `test-module(tests/)` to an existing rust package.

my package directory tree looks similar to below `example_package`

```
example_package
|
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── lib.rs
|   ├── other_module.rs
│   ├── main.rs
└── tests
    ├── lib.rs
    ├── test1.rs
    └── test_fixtures
        ├── mod.rs
        ├── test_fixture1.rs
        └── test_fixture2.rs
```

Here

- `test-fixtures/` -  is the directory which has common test inputs used in actual testcases.
- `test1.rs` - is the actual testcase which imports `test-fixtures/` and tests a testcase.

But when I tried to import `fixtures` in `test1.rs` as below

```
//tried all below three different ways
use crate::test_fixtures;
//use self::test_fixtures;
//use super::test_fixtures;
```

The code fails at compile time.

```
 --> tests/test1.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use crate::test_fixtures;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `test_fixtures` in the root
```

What is the right way to import a submodule in another submodule which are part of `tests/`?

**Code:**

```
// tests$ cat lib.rs 
pub mod test_fixtures;
pub mod test1;
```

```
// tests$ cat test_fixtures/mod.rs 
pub mod test_fixture1;
pub mod test_fixture2;
```

```
// tests$ cat test_fixtures/test_fixture1.rs 
pub fn test_fixture1() {
    
    print!("test_fixture1");
}
```

```
// tests$ cat test_fixtures/test_fixture2.rs 
pub fn test_fixture2() {
    
    print!("test_fixture2");
}
```

```
// tests$ cat test1.rs 
use crate::test_fixtures;
//use self::test_fixtures;
//use super::test_fixtures;
pub fn test1() {
    println!("running test1");
    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in the book, section Test Organisation, subsection [Submodules in Integration Tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#submodules-in-integration-tests):

> As mentioned earlier, each file in the tests directory is compiled as its own separate crate.
>
> [...]
>
> After we’ve created tests/common/mod.rs, we can use it from any of the integration test files as a module. Here’s an example of calling the setup function from the it_adds_two test in tests/integration_test.rs:
>
> ```rust
> use adder;
>
> mod common;
>
> #[test]
> fn it_adds_two() {
>     common::setup();
>     assert_eq!(4, adder::add_two(2));
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the mod common; declaration is the same as the module declaration we demonstrated in Listing 7-21. Then in the test function, we can call the common::setup() function.

Answer (score 2):

```
└── tests
    ├── lib.rs
    ├── test1.rs
    └── test_fixtures
        ├── mod.rs
        ├── test_fixture1.rs
        └── test_fixture2.rs
```

The file structure presented makes an incorrect assumption. *The tests folder is not a library crate*. Adding a file named `lib.rs` inside the tests folder will *not* declare modules for use on all integration tests.

Instead, declare the common modules (such as `test_fixtures`) in each integration test file, or create a helper library which is shared by all of them.

See also:

- [What is an idiomatic way to have shared utility functions for integration tests and benchmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539729/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-to-have-shared-utility-functions-for-integration-tests)
- [Cannot import a module in an integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867652/cannot-import-a-module-in-an-integration-test)

Answer (score 1):

Your `tests/test1.rs` file should look like this,

```
mod test_fixtures;

#[test]
fn test1() {
    test_fixtures::test_fixture2
}
```

Notice, that you need to use `mod` to use the local module.

This tells the rust compiler to include a file named `test_fixtures.rs` or alternatively look for `test_fixtures` folder with `mod.rs` file in it.