# Unresolved import `crate::<my_type>`

Tags: rust, import, rust-cargo

I am doing a bunch of tests in Rust to check that every function inside my library works well. Some of these functions take a pointer to a struct in parameter. Therefore I wrote what this struct looks like in a separate file `list.rs`, and I intended to use it in other files that need this type for the tests. But then, when I put `use crate::t_list` in my test files, I get the following error for a reason I don't quite understand:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::t_list`
 --> tests/ft_list_push_front.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use crate::t_list;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `t_list` in the root
```

I have the following file hierarchy:

```
.
├── libasm.a
└── libasm_tester
    ├── build.rs
    ├── Cargo.toml
    ├── src
    │   ├── list.rs
    │   └── main.rs
    └── tests
        └── ft_list_push_front.rs
```

with the following content:
list.rs:

```rust
use std::ffi::c_void;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct t_list {
    pub data: *mut c_void,
    pub next: *mut t_list,
}
```

main.rs:

```rust
pub mod list;

fn main() {
    println!("Run `cargo test` to test your libasm!");
}
```

ft_list_push_front.rs:

```rust
use crate::t_list;
use std::{
    ffi::{c_void, CString},
    ptr::{null, null_mut},
};

extern "C" {
    fn ft_list_push_front(list: *mut *mut t_list, data: *const c_void) -> ();
}

#[test]
fn ft_list_push_front_00() {
    /* ... */
}
```

And doing so, I was expecting to be able to run `cargo test` without issues, but it seems that cargo doesn't find my `t_list` declaration when compiling for some reasons that I don't know. I am still a beginner with Rust and cargo, so if anyone more an expert than me can help me, I would be very grateful.

Have a nice day!

EDIT: I added the declaration of the `list` module in my `main.rs`, but this doesn't fix the problem, the error stays the same. I've also tried to put the module in the `tests` folder, but there too, it doesn't change anything. Finally, I've tried to rename `list.rs` into `lib.rs`. This last change triggered new linking issues, but I figured out how to fix them, using the `#[link(name = "asm")]` attribute instead of the `println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=..");` line in my `build.rs` (for some reasons I don't quite understand, having a `lib.rs` made this line not working anymore). But after this new problem was fixed, I was indeed able to `use libasm_tester::t_list;` in my `tests/ft_push_front.rs` file!

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The duplicate applied to your question: rename `list.rs` to `lib.rs` and access it with `use libasm_tester::t_list` in `ft_list_push_front.rs`.

Comment: Binaries (main.rs) cannot have integration tests, only libraries can. You will have to add lib.rs and inside it `pub mod list;` and inside main.rs refer to it as the crate name (libasm). In the test too, don't use `crate`, use the crate name.

Answer (score 0):

You have `t_list` inside of `list.rs`, but you haven't declared the `list` module anywhere.

In your `main.rs` you probably want to add `pub mod list;` and then you will be able to `use crate::list::t_list;`.

Comment: Indeed I forgot to declare the module, but even adding this line to my `main.rs` doesn't allow me to `use::crate::list:::t_list` in my files placed in the `tests` folder.
Also, I've checked this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867652/cannot-import-a-module-in-an-integration-test, which seems to be a similar issue, but not the same, and after some tries, it didn't fix my problem either. Any other ideas?